# URL Redirection %2 is missing in output

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

target and source URL

```
RewriteRule ^/wps/(.*)/banking/accounts/savings/tc hostname/wps/wcm/connect/021eabaa-9e43-4e4e-970d-ca13a37e9e9/ [B,L,R=302]
```

URL is redirecting to target URL but when i try to hit the target this is the output :

```
hostname/wps/wcm/connect/021eabaa-9e43-4e4e-970d-ca13a37e9e9f/
```

where "%2" is missing in output, i used [B] flag but am unable to get "%2" in output, i tried [NE] also

Comment: Could you edit your question? It's impossible to read right now, never mind understand.

Comment: target and source URL RewriteRule ^/wps/(.*)/banking/accounts/savings/tc* hostname/wps/wcm/connect/021eabaa-9e43-4e4e-970d-ca13a37e9e9f/… [B] [L,R=302] URL is redirecting to target URL but when i try to hit the target this is the output hostname/wps/wcm/connect/021eabaa-9e43-4e4e-970d-ca13a37e9e9f/… were "%2" is missing in output, i used [B] flag but am unable to get "%2" in output, i tried [NE] also---- please find the que